# Can I generate registration token for GCM using my app server?

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a list of Device Id's with me but the *regID* column of the table got deleted. Is there a way I can send push notifications via GCM with just Device ids?

App is registered on GCM with those Device IDs, only the *regID* got deleted. The app server I am using is in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Can I generate registration token for GCM using my app server?*

Unfortunately, there is no way to generate, re-generate or refresh registration tokens from an App Server. All of these processes are done on the client app's side.

> *Is there a way I can send push notifications via GCM with just Device IDs?*

Nope. The registration token is the value needed by GCM (or even FCM). You'll have to retrieve the tokens from the client apps somehow and save them (again) accordingly. Having some backups of these tokens would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no. For send notification you must have a regID what was created on device.